# datadog: set traceId manually

Tags: python, datadog

I am reading this [tutorial](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/advanced/manual_instrumentation/?tab=python):

I would like to set `traceId` be equal `requestId`. How can I do it using `ddtrace` api?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I want to do the same!